# How to set path to ruby on win 7

Tags: ruby, windows-7, git-bash

I am using git-bash in win7. I have installed c:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe. I've added c:/ruby/bin/ to my PATH environmental variable and restarted. however when I do:

```
$ which ruby
/c/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/ruby

$ echo $PATH
/c/ruby/bin:/c/st:/c/Users/Bill/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/c/python27:/c/Python27/Lib/sitepackages/django/bin:/c/Python27/Scripts:/c/MinGW/bin:/d/opscode/chef/bin:/d/opscode/chef/embedded/bin:/d/VirtualBox/VBoxManage:/d/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/c/opscode/chef/bin:/c/opscode/chef/embedded/bin:/c/ProgramData/Composer/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/git/cmd:/c/nodejs/:/c/Users/Bill/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Ruby193/bin
```

How do I change this to "c:/ruby/bin/" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following line to `/c/Users/your-username/.bashrc` file to make the `/c/ruby/bin` placed before any other directory in the `PATH`:

```
export PATH=/c/ruby/bin:$PATH
```

Or, start git bash, and issue the following command:

```
echo 'export PATH=/c/ruby/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

**UPDATE**

If above still does not work, check whether the directory `/c/ruby` does exists. If it does, check whethere `ruby.exe` file is in the directory `/c/ruby/bin`.

If the directory does not exist, replace `/c/ruby/...` with the one really exists.

Comment: I've followed your directions but there is no change when I try "which ruby"

Comment: @user61629, Could you show the result of this command: `echo $PATH`

Comment: @user61629, Is there `ruby.exe` in the directory `/c/ruby/bin`? In my machine there's no `/c/ruby` directory, but `/c/Ruby21-x64`. Check the directory exist.

Comment: actually there is not even a /c/ruby, I must have deleted that a long time ago. should I remove it from the path?

Comment: @user61629, Replace the directory path with the real one that exist. For example, if you use the same ruby version as mine: `export PATH=/c/ruby21-x64/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Ok Thank you. I ended up removing some old, now non existent directories from the path environmental variable, and its now working correctly. - Bill